# How to take multiple inputs from the user in Javascript? How to declare variable for all?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing JavaScript meal nutrition calculator. It is a template with 5 rows, every each row got 4 inputs, so twenty in total, type=value. Every input got different id.

Is there any way to read all inputs at the same time without duplicating "var x = document.getElementById('x').value" 20 times?

Best,

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<h1>Calculator</h1>
<div>ingredient: 
<input type="number" id="x" placeholder="x">
<input type="number" id="y" placeholder="y">
<input type="number" id="z" placeholder="z">
<input type="number" id="a" placeholder="a"></div>

<button onclick="calo()" id="cal">Go</button>
<h1>Facts</h1>  
</div>
<div id="result">Result is displayed here.</div>
</body>
</html>


function calo() {
const [x,y,z,a] = [...document.querySelectorAll('input')];
document.querySelector("pre").textContent = x.outerHTML + "\n" + y.outerHTML + "\n" + z.outerHTML + "\n" + a.outerHTML;

var calculate = x + y + z + a;

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = calculate;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

```
document.querySelectorAll('input')
    .forEach(input=>console.log("Id:", input.id, "Value:", input.value));
```

If you want the `input` elements declared as separate variables, you can use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Example:

```js
const [x,y,z] = document.querySelectorAll('input');
document.querySelector("pre").textContent 
      = x.outerHTML + "\n" + y.outerHTML + "\n" + z.outerHTML;
```

```html
<input type="number" id="x">
<input type="number" id="y">
<input type="number" id="z">
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: How it will look like for "type=name", for 3 inputs:
    <input type="number" id="x">
    <input type="number" id="y">
    <input type="number" id="z">

    document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(input=>console.log("Name:", input.id, "Value:", input.value));
I tried that way, but x,y and z are not declared

Comment: @Pawel What do you mean by not declared? `document.querySelectorAll` just gets a collection of all the `input` elements which you can loop through.

Comment: @Pawel I have also updated my answer to provide some additional guidance.

Comment: I would love to collect all 4 inputs and take action, after show result. Trying to understand how it works. Thank you for help

Comment: @Pawel No problem. Do you still need help with anything?

Comment: I edit my post, could you please explain why calo is not a function? is it because if missing?

Comment: @Pawel You didn't put your JavaScript in a `script` tag.

Comment: upsi, done, thank you, now I'm getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null

Comment: @Pawel That is because you directly copied the example code from my answer. You do not have a `pre` element on the page, so you should remove the line `document.querySelector("pre").textContent = x.outerHTML + "\n" + y.outerHTML + "\n" + z.outerHTML;`.

Comment: @Pawel No problem. If you face any other issues, you may want to ask a new question.